# EF Code First + remove orphans which marked as Modified (IsDeleted = 1)

Tags: ef-code-first, repository-pattern

I have the next problem. My code context + model:

```
public class MediaPlanContext : DbContext
{
    public MediaPlanContext() : base(lazyLoading:false) {}

    public DbSet<MediaPlan> MediaPlan { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MovieType> MovieType { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MediaPlanItem> MediaPlanItems { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<MediaPlanItem>()
            .HasKey(mpi => new {mpi.Id, mpi.MediaPlanId});
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<MediaPlanItem>()
            .Property(mpi => mpi.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<MediaPlan>()
            .HasMany(mp => mp.MediaPlanItems)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(mpi => mpi.MediaPlanId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
    }        
}

public class MediaPlan : IBaseObject
{
    public virtual ICollection<MediaPlanItem> MediaPlanItems { get; set; }
}

public class MediaPlanItem : IBaseObject
{
    public int MediaPlanId {get;set;}
    public MediaPlan MediaPlan {get;set;} 
}

public interface IBaseObject
{
    public int Id {get;}
    public DateTime DateCreated {get;}
    public DateTime DateModified {get;set;}
}
```

Also I use repository to handle with my objects (`IBaseObject-s`) with root-object MediaPlan.
When object in my DB will become deleted I mark entity (record) as `IsDeleted = 1` and I have some logic in my repository class to handle regular delete as update, change `EntityState` to `Modified` instead of `Deleted`.

Problem with the next code:

```
var rep = new MediaPlanRepository(new MediaPlanContext());
var withItems = rep.GetWithMediaPlanItems();
var m1 = withItems.First();
var mpi1 = m1.MediaPlanItems.First();
m1.MediaPlanItems.Remove(mpi1); // 6 items before remove
// 5 items after remove
rep.SaveChanges();
// 6 items after save changes :(
```

Question: Can I handle the moment after saveChanges occurs and detach my `IsDeleted = 1` entity? Is is resolve my problem?

Remark: Related entities loaded to root object as [projection](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/use-projections-and-a-repository-to-fake-a-filtered-eager-load/) and as Julie says in paragraph 'Scenario When This May Not Work As Expected' can produce problems with entities that is already tracked by context.

Comment: I overrided SaveChanges in DbContext and inserted my after save logic as detaching my modified objects (marked as IsDeleted = 1), it's worked, but I think it's not good solution.</br>

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var result = base.SaveChanges();
    // AfterSave code
    var isDeletedEntities = EfContext.ChangeTracker
        .Entries()  
        .Select(dbE => new {  
             DBEntity = dbE,  
             BaseObject = (dbE.Entity as IBaseObject)})  
        .Where(dbe => dbe.BaseObject.IsDeleted);  

    foreach (var isDeletedEntity in isDeletedEntities)  
    {  
        isDeletedEntity.DBEntity.State = EntityState.Detached;  
    }
}
```